# Compare Objectify Key<> with datastore key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Here is my scenario

```
public boolean contains(Book book, Page needle){
  for(com.googlecode.objectify.Key<Page> hay: book.getPages()){
    if( needle.getKey().equals(hay) ) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

So basically Book and Page are `@Entity`s. Book contains a set of pages as `List<Key<Page>>`. I need to find if a certain page exists in a given book. How might I compare the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the native datastore `Key` from a `Key<>` using the `Key<>.getRaw()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getRaw()](http://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/5.1.5/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.html#getRaw--) method to get a `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key` instance

[image]